# $X=\operatorname{grad} f$ if and only if $X f \equiv|X|_{g}^{2}$ and $X$ is orthogonal to the level sets of $f$ at all regular points of $f .$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Lee's IRM book,there is a problem 2-10 which needs to prove the following result:

Suppose $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a nowhere-vanishing vector field. Prove that $X=\operatorname{grad} f$ if and only if $X f \equiv|X|_{g}^{2}$ and $X$ is orthogonal to the level sets of $f$ at all regular points of $f .$

My attempt,the only if part is obvious,for the "if" part first since for regular level set $f^{-1}(c) = S$ (such that $c$ is regular value) such that $\dim(S) = \dim(M) - 1$ hence there exist a dimension 1 subspace orthogonal to $S$ (we know both $\operatorname{grad} f$ and $X$ orthogonal to $S$),hence **for each $p \in S$** we have $kX=\operatorname{grad} f$  for some function $k$ since $Xf = |X|_g^2$ we have $ k = 1$.

I have no idea how to prove the final step,which needs to prove **for each $p \in M$** (not only for those $p$ lies on some regular level set),do we need to use sard theorem ?I have no idea how to make it precise.

Comment: As you've noted after fixing an arbitrary $p\in S$ you can write $kX_p=\text{grad}\, f(p)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$.  Try calculating $k\langle X,X\rangle$ in two different ways.

Comment: Do you mean $Xf = df(X) = <\operatorname{grad} f,X> = k<X,X>$? @Adam T

Comment: Yep, exactly.  And what does $Xf$ equal?

Comment: I have proved that $k = 1$ which shows $\operatorname{grad} f = X$ for each $p \in S$, what I don't know  is for arbitrary $p \in M$ not only $p \in S$ those $p$ may not lies in the regular level set? @AdamT

Comment: At a critical point $p$, $\text{d}f_p = 0$, so that $\text{grad }f_p = X_p = 0$. Can you conclude from this?

Comment: Notice that, if I am reading correctly, the condition $X f \equiv|X|_{g}^{2}$ holds at any point. So that you can apply it at a critical point.

Comment: since we assume $X$  is non-vanishing vector field combined with this condition  implies that every $p$ is regular for $f$ correct? @Laz

Comment: Ohh, right, so $X$ is nowhere vanishing. Then $X f \equiv|X|_{g}^{2}$ automatically implies that $f$ cannot have critical points.